# SFDC SSO and credential flow

Tags: single-sign-on

Can someone provide guidance on how to achieve the following scenario:

We have an application which will be secured using an Id Provider (thinktecture v2) and this application will be embedded within Sales Force accessed by clicking a custom link. We want to have it such that a user will log into SF once and then when they access the external application they will be automatically authenticated within that app using the credentials from Sales Force.

This application wont be accessing Sales Force data but we would like to prevent the situation of having the user authenticate twice - once to SFDC and again to our app the first time they use it. All of my readings on SSO so far only seem to work with external applications that access the SF APIs for data and I feel as if this scenario is the reverse (or maybe they share similarities).

Has anyone had experience of such a situation, if so could they provide some pointers, or even advise if such a thing is possible ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce supports SSO to external sites through a web tab in a few ways:

- Create a "[Canvas app](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/platform_connectpre/canvas_framework.pdf)" that receives a signed message from salesforce.com.
- Create a "Web tab" that provides the Session ID and Server URL to your site; you can use those parameters to access the REST or SOAP API to validate the user.
- Use OAuth2 to request a session token via a "[Connected App](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Connected_Apps)", which resembles a "Facebook"-style login.